# How to add these select options in flutter. Is any package available

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]
Is any package available to make this type of options available which upon clicking gets selected.

Tried showing a list of custom buttons

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/multi_select_flutter

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flutter [multi-select](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_select_flutter) package with chips -

```
MultiSelectDialogField(
  items: _animals.map((e) => MultiSelectItem(e, e.name)).toList(),
  listType: MultiSelectListType.CHIP,
  onConfirm: (values) {
    _selectedAnimals = values;
  },
),
```